# Написание регулярного выражения для input [type=range]

Tags: javascript, html

Написание сложного регулярного выражения, которое позволяет вводить только те значения, которые есть в input [type=range]

Не спрашивайте, зачем мне такое понадобилось, но сижу ломаю голову с регулярками, чтоб попытаться достичь такого результата.

Цель: позволять в `input` вводить только ТЕ значения, которые есть у `input[type=range]`. Все бы ничего, но должны поддерживаться и натуральные и дробные числа (включая отрицательные – то есть со знаком `-` перед числом).

Вот есть несколько полей и ползунков:

```html
<div class="pinned-default">
  <span>Диапазон – от -25 до 25. Ход ползунка – 0.1</span>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" class="range-value-input" />
  <br/>
  <input type="range" min="-25" max="25" step="0.1" />
</div>
<div class="pinned-default">
  <span>Диапазон – от 60 до 450. Ход ползунка – 1</span>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" class="range-value-input" />
  <br/>
  <input type="range" min="60" max="450" step="1" />
</div>
<div class="pinned-default">
  <span>Диапазон – от 2000 до 20000. Ход ползунка – 50</span>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" class="range-value-input" />
  <br/>
  <input type="range" min="2000" max="20000" step="50" />
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем это регулярки? `val > min && val < max && (val / step) % 1 === 0`.

Comment: @Other  В ответ добавьте plz.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем это регулярки?
`val > min && val < max && (val / step) % 1 === 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Вижу что появился хороший ответ, но если Ваша цель - потренировать регулярку, то вот моя идея:
-?(((2[0-4])|([0-1]\d))(.\d+)?|(25))
Для диапазона от -25 до 25 включительно.

но для каждого диапазона придется чуток модифицировать.

В чем суть регулярки. Минус может быть может не быть - не влияет никак ни на что далее. Если первая цифра - 2, то вторая может быть от 0 до 5, для соблюдения диапазона. Если первая цифра 0 или 1, то вторая может быть любой, так как за 25 все равно не выйдем. Дальше, если целое число в пределе от -24 до 24, то дробная часть может быть, а может и не быть. Если есть - состоит из любых значений, все равно за диапазон не выйдем. Либо 25.

Comment: Проблема в шаге. Т. е. если автор поставит шаг, скажем, `1`, то `15.4` не будет верным.

Comment: но почему? Моя регулярка подходит и для дробных чисел в том числе.

Comment: Да, в этом и смысл - Ваша регулярка найдёт дробь, но шаг накладывает ограничение - число должно быть кратно шагу. А дробь, в данном случае, не подходит (нельзя отложить `15.4` шагая целыми числами).

Comment: @Other ага, я понял. Так интереснее